# Cornerstone error "Could not convert ###error### into a number"

Tags: svn, cornerstone

Cornerstone 2+3 I get the error message "Could not convert ###error### into a number" when I try to open a repository. The Repository is made by "Adding Workspace" from an existing Subversion Local Workspace.

The cornerstone operations on the workspace work fine. Only the Repository has this problem.

The first thing I have doen is to check the repository on the server:

```
svnadmin verify <path-to-the-repo>
```

This gives the error (after some lines of verification of the repo):

```
svnadmin: E160006 No such revision 136
```

No idea how that has happened. Obviously I do not have a backup of the repo. I have no open-branches, the repo is simple so I can use the latest Workspace and create a brand-new repo without any history.
The question is however: What to do if I have had branches.
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I found that upgrading a repo from version 3 format to version 6 format this occurred because I used svnadmin dump/load to make the conversion, then renamed the repositories to make the same named repository be the upgraded repo.

It seems the latest software caches so causes some grief when the same repo is effectively swapped in situ.  Simply restart the webserver(apache in my case) and it seems to solve the problem.